# Model Lightning bug

Tags: modeling

I have a strange lightning issue with my model. It looks like it's curved,but it's completely flat surface. How can I fix this? (I tried recalculating normals)

File:
[image]

[image: bug]

Comment: please share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: it may be flat but it probably try to shade smooth with the adjacent faces, you should be able to fix that with a good topology